# Extract sound files from a powerpoint

Tags: python, python-3.x, powerpoint, python-pptx

I'm trying to extract sounds files from a powerpoint using Python . This is what I wrote :

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.enum.shapes import MSO_SHAPE_TYPE

file = open(filepath , 'rb') 
prs = Presentation(file)

for slide in prs.slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if shape.shape_type == MSO_SHAPE_TYPE.MEDIA:
            print('Found one')
```

But even if there's a mp3 file on every slides it didn't find anything, so for every shape object I printed shape.shape_type and strangely no GraphicFrame object is present , just Picture,Text and Auto-shape.

How can I find and extract them?

Comment: `pptx` files are actually `zip` files, have you tried opening them as zip and looking for the media files in there? If there's no need to correlate the media file and the slide it's inserter, this is probably a very inexpensive and easy solution.

Comment: Audio is embedded in a "Picture" shape, which it looks like `python-pptx` doesn't expose elegantly at the moment.  Probably the only option is going to be digging into the ZIP archive.  More info here: http://officeopenxml.com/prSlide-multiMedia.php

Comment: Thanks ! I managed to do it converting the file to zip !

Comment: As Havenard said, opening up the .pptx files as ZIP archives is going to be the easiest solution.  Audio files appear to be stored in `/ppt/media/`.  If you have enough to warrant automating, if you just need to bulk-extract all the audio files without regard to how/where they're used, it would be a lot easier to grab all of them out of that folder than to parse all the references to them.  If you don't need to parse the references I'd put the break-even point for automation around 50 files, otherwise probably closer to 500.  If you have less than that, then I'd recommend doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Aspose.Slides for Python](https://products.aspose.com/slides/python-net/). This library allows to extract sound files from audio frames as shown below:

```py
import aspose.slides as slides

from aspose.slides import AudioFrame

with slides.Presentation("example.pptx") as presentation:
    for slide in presentation.slides:
        for shape in slide.shapes:
            if isinstance(shape, AudioFrame):
                audio_data = shape.embedded_audio.binary_data
                content_type = shape.embedded_audio.content_type # returns "audio/mpeg", for example
                # ...
```

Alternatively, you can get all sound files from a presentation like this:

```py
import aspose.slides as slides

from aspose.slides import AudioFrame

with slides.Presentation("example.pptx") as presentation:
    for audio in presentation.audios:
        audio_data = audio.binary_data
        content_type = audio.content_type
        # ...
```

I work as a Support Developer at Aspose.